# Python Fastest way to check and update Recursively file path if missing in DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Input file path

Example: "/A/B/C/D/E/F"

1. Check path "/A/B/C/D/E/F" exist if not go to next step
2. Remove “/F” from "/A/B/C/D/E/F" and check "/A/B/C/D/E/"present in system_file_paths

   a.  If present, Create F path

   b.  Return F _ID

   c.  If "/A/B/C/D/E” not present, go to next step
3. Remove /E/F from "/A/B/C/D/E/F" and check “/A/B/C/D" present in system_file_paths

   a.  If present, create E/F

   b.  Return F _ID

   c.  If "/A/B/C/D” not present, go to next step
4. Remove /D/E/F from "/A/B/C/D/E/F" and check “/A/B/C" present in system_file_paths list

   a.  If present, create D/E/F

   b.  Return F _ID

   c.  If "/A/B/C” not present, go to next step

Do, Until last step A, in case not present,

I have written code, it is  working as expected, but performance is downgrading because i have huge number of files, like millons and file_path lengths in 1000's

Note: I am not trying to create any directories inside OS, I am updating in Application DB

My Code:

```
# Random system generation input paths for testing 
import uuid
def file_path_list(num):
    file_path_list = []
    temp_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    for i in range(num):
        temp = "{0}".format(i)
        for j in temp_list:
            temp += "{0}".format(j)
        file_path_list.append(temp)

    temp_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','1','2','3','4']
    for i in range(num):
        temp = "{0}".format(i)
        for j in temp_list:
            temp += "{0}".format(j)

        file_path_list.append(temp)

    temp_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    for i in range(num):
        temp = "{0}".format(i)
        for j in temp_list:
            temp += "{0}".format(j)
        file_path_list.append(temp)
    

    return file_path_list

path_trees = file_path_list(10)

system_file_paths = {}
for path in path_trees:
    system_file_paths[path] = str(uuid.uuid4())

# ************             system paths generation completed  for testing       ***************

# Input file 
file_path = 'A/B/C/D/E/F'

def update_db(path_name):
    _id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    system_file_paths[path_name] = _id
    return _id


# checking File path exist
def check_file_path_exists(file_path):
    if file_path in system_file_paths:
        return True
    return False

# Looking solution, to speed up process performance, by applying any suitable algorithm and reduces multiple checks, in this method
def process_to_update_db(file_path):
    # Split file path 
    file_path_split = file_path.split("/")
    # Iterate loop
    for reverse_path_indent in range(len(file_path_split) -1 , -1, -1):

        # If iterate until last value, create root path
        if reverse_path_indent == 0:
            if not check_file_path_exists(file_path_split[0]):
                _id = update_db(file_path_split[0])
            for path_indent in range(1, len(file_path_split)):
                file_path = "/".join(file_path_split[0: path_indent + 1])
                _id = update_db(file_path)
            return _id
            #_id = update_db(file_path_split[0])

        file_path_check = "/".join(file_path_split[0: reverse_path_indent])
        if not check_file_path_exists(file_path_check):
            continue
        else:
            for path_indent in range(reverse_path_indent, len(file_path_split)):
                file_path = "/".join(file_path_split[0: path_indent + 1])
                _id = update_db(file_path)
            return _id





if not check_file_path_exists(file_path):
    _id = process_to_update_db(file_path)
    print(system_file_paths)
    # Cross Verify path is created
    if check_file_path_exists(file_path):
        print(0)
    else:
        print(1)
```

Comment: Not python, but maybe helpful: In linux the command `mkdir -p /A/B/C/D/E/F` does exactly what you want. Create all parent directories (iff needed).

Comment: Yes,  But I am not using OS, In Application we need to implement similar thing

Comment: You may achieve @MrSmith42's suggestion through `os.makedirs` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some more test cases, and corrected my code:

```
# Random system generation input paths for testing 
import uuid, json

system_file_paths = {}

# ************             system paths generation completed  for testing       ***************

# Input file
file_path = [ 
    'A',
    'A/B/C/D/E/F',
    'A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/K',
    'A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W',
    'A/X/Y',
    'A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W/Z',
    'A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/A/B/C/D',
    'A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/K/L/A/B/C/D/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W'
]

def update_db(path_name):
    global create_loop_count
    create_loop_count += 1
    _id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    system_file_paths[path_name] = _id
    return _id


# checking File path exist
def check_file_path_exists(file_path):
    if file_path in system_file_paths:
        try:
            return system_file_paths[file_path]
        except KeyError:
            return False
    return False

# Looking solution, to speed up process performance, by applying any suitable algorithm and reduces multiple checks, in this method
def process_to_update_db_original(file_path):
    global search_loop_count
    # Split file path 
    file_path_split = file_path.split("/")
    # Iterate loop
    for reverse_path_indent in range(len(file_path_split) -1 , -1, -1):
        search_loop_count += 1
        # If iterate until last value, create root path
        if reverse_path_indent == 0:
            if not check_file_path_exists(file_path_split[0]):
                _id = update_db(file_path_split[0])
            for path_indent in range(1, len(file_path_split)):
                file_path = "/".join(file_path_split[0: path_indent + 1])
                _id = update_db(file_path)
            return _id
            #_id = update_db(file_path_split[0])

        file_path_check = "/".join(file_path_split[0: reverse_path_indent])
        if not check_file_path_exists(file_path_check):
            continue
        else:
            for path_indent in range(reverse_path_indent, len(file_path_split)):
                file_path = "/".join(file_path_split[0: path_indent + 1])
                _id = update_db(file_path)
            return _id

# Looking solution, to speed up process performance, by applying any suitable algorithm and reduces multiple checks, in this method
def process_to_update_db_new(file_path):
    global search_loop_count
    # first of all, check to see if the path already exist:
    try:
        return system_file_paths[file_path]
    except KeyError:
        # do things the hard way
        # Split file path 
        if file_path:
            file_path_split = [file_path]
        if "/" in file_path:
            file_path_split = file_path.split("/")
        while '' in file_path_split:
            file_path_split.remove('')
        start_index = 0
        end_index = len(file_path_split) - 1
        current_path = ''
        build_path_start_index = 0
        # bias seach to the last directory minus one, assuming that most directory lists add a new path at the end
        current_index = end_index - 1

        # let's do a binary search on the paths to find where we need to start adding directories
        while start_index != end_index:
            search_loop_count += 1

            for i in range(build_path_start_index, current_index+1):
                if i != 0:
                    current_path += '/'
                current_path += file_path_split[i]

            #print("start_index: %d, end_index: %d, current_index: %d : %s"%(start_index,end_index,current_index,current_path))

            if check_file_path_exists(current_path):
                start_index = current_index+1
                if start_index > end_index:
                    start_index = end_index
                build_path_start_index = start_index
            else:
                current_path = ''
                build_path_start_index = 0
                end_index = current_index-1
                if end_index < start_index:
                    end_index = start_index

            current_index = int((end_index-start_index)/2) + start_index

        # build up the existing path
        for i in range(build_path_start_index, start_index+1):
            if i != 0:
                current_path += '/'
            current_path += file_path_split[i]

        # do the actual insertion of the UUID for new paths
        for i in range(start_index, len(file_path_split)):
            if i == start_index:
                # check if current path exists
                if check_file_path_exists(current_path):
                    # move on to next index
                    continue
                else:
                    # current_path doesn't exist, create it below
                    pass
            else:
                # append next path item
                if i != 0:
                    current_path += '/'
                current_path += file_path_split[i]

            current_id = update_db(current_path)

        return current_id


for current_path in file_path:
    if not check_file_path_exists(current_path):
        search_loop_count = 0
        create_loop_count = 0
        _id = process_to_update_db_new(current_path)
        # Cross Verify path is created
        if check_file_path_exists(current_path):
            print("SUCCESS")
        else:
            print("!!!FAILURE!!!")
        print("search_loop_count: %d create_loop_count %d"%(search_loop_count, create_loop_count))

print(json.dumps(system_file_paths,indent=4,sort_keys=True))
```

The `create_loop_count` is the same between your original and mine, but there's a difference in the number of search loops:

```
            | search_loop_count |
------------|-------------------|
Test String | Original |  New   |
------------|----------|--------|
    1       |    1     |   0    |
    2       |    5     |   2    |
    3       |    5     |   3    |
    4       |    12    |   5    |
    5       |    2     |   1    |
    6       |    1     |   1    |
    7       |    4     |   4    |
    8       |    21    |   5    |
```

If the path lengths are in the thousands, as you said in your question, then the difference will be big.